# R codes for variation of information criterion using "mclust"

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, metric, model-based-clustering

I am developing model-based clustering.

First, I developed model-based clustering in R using "mclust."  Next, I wanted to take 75% of the sample, re-run model-based clustering and compare the results with the results from the entire dataset using variation of information or rand index.  However, I am getting stuck with the codes.

Here are the codes made available for variation of information on CRAN.

```
cl1 <-sample(1:30, 10, replace=TRUE)
cl2 <- c(cl1[1:5], sample(1:3, 5, replace=TRUE))
vi.dist(cl1,cl2)
vi.dist(cl1,cl2, parts=TRUE)
```

Here is how I developed my clustering solutions:

```
model <-Mclust(data[,18:22])
```

model based clustering solution using entire dataset and data is the name of my dataset using columns 18 to 22

```
random <- data[rbinom(nrow(data), 1,.75)==1,]
```

developed a random sample

```
randommodel <-Mclust(random[,18:22])
```

model-based clustering using the random sample

```
cl1 <- (model$classification)
cl2 <- (randommodel$classification)
vi.dist(cl1,cl2)
```

my attempt at variation of information using R codes, result failed because `cl1 and cl2 are not the same length`.

So, how do I make the two solutions the same length given that the two solutions have a different number of observations?  Or, am I trying to use variation of information incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

## clustering with entire database

```
modela <-Mclust(data[,18:22])
summary(modela, parameters = TRUE)
modela$classification
    modela$BIC
```

## clustering using 75% of data

```
subsample <- sample(1:nrow(data), 530, replace=FALSE)
mysample <-data[subsample,]
modelb <-Mclust(mysample[,18:22])
summary(modelb, parameters = TRUE)
modelb$classification
    modelb$BIC
```

## adjusted rand index

```
arandi(modela$classification[subsample],modelb$classification)
```

## variation of information

```
vi.dist(modela$classification[subsample],modelb$classification)
```

Comment: Can someone check to see if these codes for comparing the results of clustering when including the entire dataset and when including just 75% of the dataset (i.e., 530 is 75% of the dataset in this case)?